# How to get data by passing id into router from one vue component to another vue component through laravel axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, error-handling, vue-component, vue-router

Employee.vue Component

```
<tr role="row" class="odd" v-for="(employee, index) in employees" :key="index">
   <td>{{ index+1 }}</td>
   <td><router-link :to="/employee-profile/+employee.id">{{ employee.name }}</router-link></td>
</tr>
```

> I am sending employee **id** from here to **EmployeeDetails.vue** by routes in ***app.js***

```
let routes = [
    { path: '/employee', component: require('./components/office/Employee.vue').default },
    { path: '/employee-details/:id', component: require('./components/office/EmployeeDetails').default },
]
```

Here is my EmployeeDetails.vue component

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                employees:{},
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            let id = this.$route.params.id

            axios.get('api/employee-details/'+id)
                  .then(response => {
                      this.employees = response.data;
                  });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is **api.php** file that I have called route through API resources

```
Route::get('employee-details/{id}', 'API\EmployeeController@employeeDetails');
```

and Here is my Controller EmployeeController.php where I have called function for return data

```
public function employeeDetails($id)
{
   return DB::table('employees')->where('id', $id)->get(); 
}
```

> But the problem is: Data is not showing and return a error message in my ***console***. Error is given below. Actually I want How can I solve this error.

```
app.js:81221 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

found in

---> <EmployeeProfile> at resources/js/components/office/EmployeeProfile.vue
       <Root>
app.js:82484 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the id you are passing in the router link is incorrect.

It should be :

```
<router-link :to="`/employee-profile/${employee.id}`">{{ employee.name }}</router-link>
```

Comment: I have tried by this line but error is still showing 
```
<router-link :to="`/employee-details/${employee.id}`">{{ employee.name }}</router-link>
```

Comment: yes. here is github link of EmployeeDetails.vue file
[link](https://github.com/ruhulrahman/Inventory/blob/master/resources/js/components/office/EmployeeDetails.vue)

Comment: Your error mentions `/js/components/office/EmployeeProfile.vue` but I don't see this file in your repo ?

Comment: bro. this is not EmployeeProfile.vue. The correction is EmployeeDetails.vue. check it again

Comment: Actually I am using in axios like this
`
axios.get('api/details/'+this.$route.params.id)
                .then((data)=>{
                    this.employees = data.data;
                })
`
but route is being going this: http://localhost:8000/employee-details/api/details/2
what's the problem here?